# Facing Mode for my phone webapp is suddenly not working

Tags: javascript

Suddenly environment just stop working for my camera selection why? Essentially on the screen the use can click choose camera and a drop down selection of front or back is shown. once one is selected the user clicks get camera and it then displays on screen. Well why did environment just suddenly stop working, I have read comment on the web saying facingmode is not useable on chrome.

```
      if (typeof currentStream !== 'undefined') {
        stopMediaTracks(currentStream);
      }
      const videoConstraints = {};
      videoConstraints.width = 332;
      videoConstraints.height = 255;
      if (select.value === '') {
        videoConstraints.facingMode = "environment";
      } else {
        videoConstraints.deviceId = { exact: select.value };
      }
      const constraints = {
        video: videoConstraints,
        audio: false
      };
```

Comment: you sound like my project maneger, i have no ideia what you want me to do. Add more detail to your question, please be more specific